# How to track page change (Chrome Context Script plugin)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm writing a simple Chrome plugin that's intended to delete DOM elements from some site.

manifest.json

```
{ 
  "name": "bla", 
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "bla", 
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", 
  "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

myscript.js

```
window.onload = start;

function start()
{
    var ads = document.getElementById("left_ads");
    ads.parentNode.removeChild(ads);
    alert("bla");
}
```

When I load a target page everything works perfectly: `div id="left_ads"` is removed as intended. But, when I click a link to a page which also has a similar `div id="left_ads"` my script fails to work. I know that probably I should choose some other event, not `window.onload()`, but which one?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I've found a solution to this. I used background html file.
So, the plugin now looks like this:

manifest.json:

```
{ 
  "name": "bla", 
  "version": "1.0", 
  "description": "bla", 
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", 
  "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

background.html:

```
<html>
  <script>
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(start);

    function start(tabID, changeInfo, tab)
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "myscript.js"   })

    }

  </script>
</html>
```

myscript.js:

```
var ads = document.getElementById("left_ads");
ads.parentNode.removeChild(ads);
```

Works OK, on every page.